# Effect of weights on the Louvain communities detected

Tags: graphs, community

The Louvain method for community detection aims to optimize modularity and hence detect communities in the given graph. In case of a weighted graph would it be valid to assume that an edge with a higher weight would be prioritized to be part of a community as against an edge with a lower weight while optimizing modularity ?

Comment: I would say vice versa. Weight - should be thought as length of path, so high weight - nodes are far from each other - should be prioritized as   separate communities members. Hope I did not forget something ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, weights are interpreted as a strength of connection in the context of modularity.  This is perhaps easiest to see using the interpretation of unweighted modularity as

> The fraction of edges within communities minus the expected such fraction in a random graph with the same degree sequence.

Switching the adjacency matrix to the weighted adjacency matrix to get the weighted modularity just changes this to

> The fraction of total weights within communities minus the expected such fraction in a random weighted graph with the same total weights at each vertex.

---

That said, you do have to be careful.  There are community detection methods that do treat weights as distances:
[SO: meaning of weights in community detection algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49311269/10495893)

It may be worth running a simple example when first using a specific algorithm implementation; e.g., with $G=C_4$, weight one perfect matching very much higher than the other, the communities should end up being two $K_2$s, and you want to know whether they contain the high- or low- weight edges.